# ASP.NET MVC cookie duplicate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

When I add a cookie in the Response, the Request is getting two duplicate cookies. Here is the code:

```
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[Constants.CART_COOKIE_KEY]; // 1 "cart" coookie received from a client browser.
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        Request.Cookies.Remove(Constants.CART_COOKIE_KEY); //remove it. Now there is no cookie in the Request
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2);
        cookie.Value = "test";
       //Response is empty until now
        Response.Cookies.Set(cookie); // add to the Response, but now there are even two "cart" cookies in the Request. WTF?
    }
```

It's very important for me to have harmonized values, because I still have to use the value from the Request in the remaining process. But when I add modified value to Response, Request is getting to the horrible mess.

Comment: can you check the count of `Request.Cookies` after you remove the cookie.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh yes, I've written it in the comment, the are no cookies, zero.

Comment: What happens if you create a new cookie variable and do not use the existing `cookie` variable?

Comment: @JamieRees all the same

Comment: but actually Response.Cookies.Add() doesn't restore duplicate. It creates only one cookie it Request

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the cookie from request and adding a new one into the response who knows in which state of the request...

May I suggest you use an `OwinMiddleware` for modifying the response cookies since you're using a compatible stack anyway?

It's pretty easy to plug into the correct phase of the request.

```
public class CartCookieMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public CartCookieMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process an individual request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"/>
    /// <returns/>
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {

        // Register an event when response headers are sent
        context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
        {
            // Get response from state
            var resp = (IOwinResponse)state;
            // Get request from state
            var req = resp.Context.Request;

            var cookie = req.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key.Equals(Constants.CART_COOKIE_KEY, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Value;

            if (cookie != null)
            {
                resp.Cookies.Delete(Constants.CART_COOKIE_KEY);
            }
            else
            {
                cookie = "test";
            }

            resp.Cookies.Append(Constants.CART_COOKIE_KEY, cookie, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = true, Secure = req.IsSecure });

        }, context.Response);

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```